# Textbox text not parsing with spaces in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog, system.management

I have a textbox that will be populated with a directory structure (for example, C:\Program Files\Visual Basic). I'm trying to use the `textbox.text` object in another variable, but when the path includes spaces the information will cut off.

Here is the offending code that populates the text box with the path:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_Script.Click
        Dim BrowseFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        BrowseFolder.ShowDialog()
        tbScript.Text = BrowseFolder.SelectedPath
    End Sub
```

Note that it uses `FolderBrowserDialog` to populate the text box, and this part works fine. I have another button click that then uses the `textbox.text` along with a specific file name within a function I defined elsewhere:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Path As String
        Path = tbScript.Text & "\Client_Perfmon.ps1"
        RunScript(Path)
    End Sub
```

It's never getting far enough to parse the file name, the exception is:

```
    Exception:Caught: "The term 'C:\Users\seanlon\Desktop\Performance\Powershell' is not
 recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again." (System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException)
    A System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException was caught: "The term
 'C:\Users\seanlon\Desktop\Performance\Powershell' is not recognized as the name of a
 cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
 a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

Comment: Your `RunScript()` function is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first button handler should check the result of ShowDialog():

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_Script.Click
    Dim BrowseFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
    If BrowseFolder.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        tbScript.Text = BrowseFolder.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Your second handler should use Path.Combine():

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbScript.Text, "Client_Perfmon.ps1")
    RunScript(Path)
End Sub
```

*It should probably check to make sure the path actually exists as well!

What does RunScript() do?

Sometimes applications require that paths with spaces be enclosed in quotation marks:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path As String = Chr(34) & System.IO.Path.Combine(tbScript.Text, "Client_Perfmon.ps1") & Chr(34)
    RunScript(Path)
End Sub
```

Comment: runscript() grabs the specified file (a Powershell script) and pulls out each line individually, putting it into a string (with line breaks where appropriate).

Why would I need to check the result of the BrowseFolder.ShowDialog()? I understand the check, but is that just to make sure that a valid directory has been used?

Comment: "OK" is returned when the user actually selects a file.  You wouldn't want to process anything if they **cancel** the dialog (there wouldn't be a selected file!).

Comment: That makes sense to me, and I added a check in to make sure that the Path to the file exists. The code still isn't working (system.io.file.exists(Path) returns false even when the file is there) but that's a different problem!